# If $ f'(c) > 0 $, then there is an $ x $ such that $ f(x) > f(c) $.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Here is the homework question that I have:

> If $ f: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R} $ is differentiable at $ c $, where $ a < c < b $ and $ f^{\prime}(c) > 0 $, prove that there exists an $ x $ such that $ c < x < b $ and $ f(x) > f(c) $.

(I appreciate your help!)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!. The policy for homework questions is that you show what you have tried yourself. This makes sure that you have at least tried to solve it yourself, but also allows other people to help you better.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: assume $f$ has a (global) maximum at $c$, conclude something about $f'(c)$ and reach a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, wow thank you so much!

Comment: Just because there is no $x$ s.t. $f(x)>f(c)$ that doesn't mean that $f(c)$ is a maximum. Remember that $x>c$

Comment: @KristofferRyhl: I had read that $c$ as $a$, t it doesn't change much in what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: You know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f^{\prime}(c)>0$, so consider what happens if $f(x)\le f(c)$ for $x>c$.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how many theorems we have at our disposal, this proof is unnecessary. I'll give it anyways just for fun though.

We have assumed that $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = l > 0$$
Therefore, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a neighborhood of $c$ where $$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-l\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$
for all $x$ in said neighborhood. What this means for such $x$ that are greater than $c$ (so that we can multiply by $x-c$ without altering the inequalities) is that: $$\quad \quad \,\,\,l-\varepsilon<\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}<\varepsilon + l \\
\begin{align} &\Rightarrow &(l-\varepsilon)(x-c)<f(x)-f(c) < (l+\varepsilon)(x-c) \end{align}$$
Take $\varepsilon = l/2$, and $x_{\varepsilon}$ close enough to $c$ (and greater than) to get $$\frac{l}{2}(x_{\varepsilon}-c) < f(x_{\varepsilon})-f(c)$$
and the left expression is greater than $0$, from which $$f(x_{\varepsilon}) > f(c)$$

As an extra, the last part of the proof would have worked for any positive $\varepsilon < l$, from which we in fact see that there is a whole open interval $(c,y)$ of points where $f(x) > f(c)$ (allowing $y = +\infty$).